# Question on messages from the typesense/docsearch-scraper

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docusaurus, typesense

We are hosting typesense on WSL where ubuntu is installed. We are trying to implement this as the search engine for our large documentation site.  Typesense  seems to be installed properly.  When the following command is run:

```
 curl http://localhost:8108/health
```

is run, the following message is displayed:

```
{"ok":true}
```

However, when the following command is run:

```
docker run -it  --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway  --env-file=docker.env -e "CONFIG=$(cat config.json | jq -r tostring)" typesense/docsearch-scraper
```

A series of messages similar to the following are displayed:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): host.docker.internal:8108
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://host.docker.internal:8108 "POST /collections/docusaurus-2_1656520440/documents/import HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:typesense.api_call:host.docker.internal:8108 is healthy. Status code: 200
> DocSearch: https://docusaurus.io/zh-CN/docs/migration 39 records)
DEBUG:typesense.api_call:Making post /collections/docusaurus-2_1656520440/documents/import
DEBUG:typesense.api_call:Try 1 to node host.docker.internal:8108 -- healthy? True
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): host.docker.internal:8108
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://host.docker.internal:8108 "POST /collections/docusaurus-2_1656520440/documents/import HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:typesense.api_call:host.docker.internal:8108 is healthy. Status code: 200
> DocSearch: https://docusaurus.io/ko/docs/migration 39 records)
DEBUG:typesense.api_call:Making post /collections/docusaurus-2_1656520440/documents/import
DEBUG:typesense.api_call:Try 1 to node host.docker.internal:8108 -- healthy? True
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): host.docker.internal:8108
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://host.docker.internal:8108 "POST /collections/docusaurus-2_1656520440/documents/import HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:typesense.api_call:host.docker.internal:8108 is healthy. Status code: 200
> DocSearch: https://docusaurus.io/pt-BR/docs/migration 39 records)
DEBUG:scrapy.core.engine:Crawled (200) <GET https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/migration> (referer: https://docusaurus.io/docs/migration)
DEBUG:scrapy.core.engine:Crawled (200) <GET https://docusaurus.io/docs/2.0.0-beta.20/migration> (referer: https://docusaurus.io/docs/migration)
DEBUG:scrapy.core.engine:Crawled (200) <GET https://docusaurus.io/fr/docs/migration> (referer: https://docusaurus.io/docs/migration)
DEBUG:typesense.api_call:Making post /collections/docusaurus-2_1656520440/documents/import
DEBUG:typesense.api_call:Try 1 to node host.docker.internal:8108 -- healthy? True
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): host.docker.internal:8108
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://host.docker.internal:8108 "POST /collections/docusaurus-2_1656520440/documents/import HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

These messages continue for a long time.

The contents of the env file are as follows:

```
TYPESENSE_API_KEY=xyz
TYPESENSE_HOST=host.docker.internal
TYPESENSE_PORT=8108
TYPESENSE_PROTOCOL=http
```

The contents of the config.json file are as follows:

```
{
  "index_name": "config",
  "start_urls": [
      {
          "url": "http://192.168.16.1:3000/docs/book",
      
      }
  ],
  "selectors": {
      "default": {
          "lvl0": ".theme-default-content h1",
          "lvl1": ".theme-default-content h2",
          "lvl2": ".theme-default-content h3",
          "lvl3": ".theme-default-content h4",
          "lvl4": ".theme-default-content h5",
          "text": ".theme-default-content p, .theme-default-content ul li, .theme-default-content table tbody tr"
      }
  },
  "strip_chars": " .,;:#"
}
```

The URL in config.json file is accurate.

The relevant part of the docusaurus.config.js file is as follows:

```
  themes: ['docusaurus-theme-search-typesense'],
  themeConfig: 

    /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').ThemeConfig} */     
         
    {
    typesense: {
      typesenseCollectionName: 'http://192.168.16.1:3000/docs/book', // Replace with your own doc site's name. Should match the collection name in the scraper settings.
      
      typesenseServerConfig: {
        nodes: [
          {
            host: 'DESKTOP-XXXXDPV',
            port: 443,
            protocol: 'https',
          },
        ],
        apiKey: 'xyz',
      },
    },
  },
```

The Typesense search box appears properly but no search results appear.

Would anyone have a clue as to what i am doing wrong?

I have scoured the Internate looking for a solution.

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: I found the solution. I needed to specify a typesense collection in the docusaurus.config.js file, as follows:

Comment: typesenseCollectionName: 'docusaurus-2_1656941105',